# AWS SWF: Running activities on different servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I have a workflow with >3 activities running on 2 servers, but I want one of the activities to run on a 3rd dedicated server i.e. this server should only execute activity x and not the entire workflow. So far (with my limited knowledge) I could make a service call in the activity to execute the process on the dedicated server and then receive a callback when it's done, but I have a feeling there must be an easier way to it.

Has anyone tried this ever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Activity and workflow tasks are delivered through [task lists](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dev-task-lists.html). By default activity is scheduled on a default task list associated to the activity type. You have to a use a different task list for the third activity and make sure that its activity worker polls on that task list.

If you are using [AWS Flow Framework for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/swf/details/flow/) then you can do it through the following annotation:

```
@Activities
@ActivityRegistrationOptions(...) // used by activity1 and activity2
public interface MyActivities {
   public void activity1();

   public void activity2();

   // override for activity3
   @ActivityRegistrationOptions(defaultTaskList="activity3", ...) 
   public void activity3();

}
```

Then use "activity3" as *taskListToPoll* constructor parameter for activity3 [ActivityWorker](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/ActivityWorker.html#ActivityWorker(com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.AmazonSimpleWorkflow,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).